Old kids' show where kids get diamonds and turn into fairies
I remember this old kids' show (I think I might have been Barbie) but the kids go to this place and the fairies wake up every morning and color everything with their diamonds. And then at some point, the kids go to the garden of gems or diamonds (can't remember which one) and the kids get their own diamonds turn into fairies and then go home to the lemonade stand.
I also remember that in one episode they turn into princesses and the end up trying on dresses and stuff like that. I can't remember that much about that episode, but it's really bugging me and I would love to know what it is called.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Kelly Dream Show, indeed a Barbie spinoff.

"Sparkle Fairy Surprise" - "Using their magic dream lockets, Kelly, Chelsie and Keeya transport themselves to the colorful world of the sparkle fairies. But in order to earn their wings and become true sparkle fairies, they have to find the fabled Garden of Jewels. It's a quest full of laughs, surprises, and challenges that not only test each girl's abilities, but also teaches them the value of teamwork."
"Three Princesses" - "Ever wonder what it would be like to be a princess for a day? Kelly, Chelsie, and Keeya find out where their magic dream lockets whisk them away to a royal kingdom. But when being a pampered princess means being kept out of all the fun, the girls decide to shake up the kingdom, mocking the royal - and reminding themselves - that being responsible for yourself can be a lot of fun too."

Opening



Found with a search for cartoons fairies color with diamonds which led me to this Reddit post
